# Determinate a continuous function given a few coordinates.

Tags: functions

Given a few Cartesian coordinate points $(x,y)$, for example: $(0, 1), (2, 3), (1, 4), (-1, -2),$ etc., is it possible determinate a function $y=f(x)$ that passes exactly for that points?

Comment: There are infinite functions passing for that points. You have to select one kind.

Comment: yes I know it. I would like to be able to "calculate" one. The fact is I don't know how to make the "choice".

Comment: The solutions given below won't work if you have two points with the same $x$ coordinate. Please ask another question if you're interested in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any set of points, we can have an infinite amount of functions which pass through them. We can do this 'naively' simply defining a function which has those values at those points then whatever values we want elsewhere. If you wanted a 'nice' function which goes through those points, the following polynomial will do:
$$
1 + (1 + (-2 - 2/3 (-1 + x)) (-2 + x)) x=\frac{-2}{3} x^3 \frac{11}{3} x+1
$$

Comment: nice thank you, but how did you get that?

Comment: I used interpolation. Given $n$ distinct points, there is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ which goes through them. You can find it by finding an interpolating polynomial. There are many ways to do this. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial   I also found this which is the simplest introduction I could find quickly  http://www.enm.bris.ac.uk/admin/courses/EMa2/Lecture%20Notes%2009-10/CGCslides03_CC.pdf   However, feel free to read on the internet about Lagrange polynomials, Newton interpolation, etc, which will teach you also how to do this. It's not hard but a bit tricky.

Comment: Write a general polynomial of degree one less than the number of points, then create a system of n equations which are the polynomial evaluated at each point.  Then solve the system of equations to get the polynomial coefficients.

Comment: @Randomize half-integer fan's method is probably the way to go about it. It is one of the slower ways of doing so but avoids having to learn all the theory and is a simple task. Therefore, it is most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can do [Lagrange interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_interpolation) to find the lowest degree polynomial that passes through the points.  If you have $n$ points, it will usually be of degree $n-1$.  The basic idea is to find a set of polynomials.  Each one is $1$ at one of your data points and $0$ at all the rest.  Then using the linearity of polynomials you construct the one that goes through your points.

For some purposes, a piecewise linear function between the points works well and requires less computation.  There are many other choices:  some people like [cubic splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) to avoid the corners.  Any numerical analysis book will have a discussion.

Comment: I also like rational polynomials for practical work.  They keep the degree of the polynomial down so they are easier to invert, and often the singularity is outside the region of interest, or is a feature of the function you are fitting to.